# Split text after first space to create new variable and modify the original string

Tags: php, string, split

I want to split a string into two variables, the first word and the rest of the string. The first word is only ever going to be one of 4 different words.

```
$string = explode (' ', $string, 2);
$word = $string[0];
$string = $string[1];
```

The above seems like it works, but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: i belive that spliting it into array if a fine solution, you will be able to interate with it fine and everything thing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php):

```
list($word, $string) = explode (' ', $string, 2);
```

But it is already fine. Regular expressions would be overkill in this case.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways you can do it. Using regular expressions, using [`strtok()`](http://php.net/strtok), etc. Using `explode()` the way you are doing is quite fine.

Comment: `strtok()` will not mutate the original string in the way that the OP's script does.

Answer (score 1):

```
list($word, $string) = explode(' ', $a, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In modern PHP, `list()` has been replaced by function-less "array destructuring" syntax.

```
[$word, $string] = explode(' ', $string, 2);
```

This will populate `$word` with the substring that occurs before the first space; the remaining substring (after the first space) will overwrite the original `$string` value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7b6XF))

```
$string = 'This is a test';

[$word, $string] = explode(' ', $string, 2);

var_dump($word, $string);
```

Output:

```
string(4) "This"
string(9) "is a test"
```

---

Caution: If the input string does not contain a space (e.g. `$string = 'This';`), then you'll get:

```
Warning: Undefined array key 1
string(4) "This"
NULL
```